# Cannot accomplish to add a xamarin.froms.android app to firebase

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication

I don't know what to do anymore, I am trying to connect my Xamarin.Forms App to Firebase.

I cannot find any suitable tutorials. I have downloaded the `Google-Service.json` and added it to my Android root Directory, I also set the build Option for the file on `GoogleServicesJson`. I made sure the file has the Name from my packagename & I also added the Android App on firebase and installed the Nugget Package `xamarin.firebase.Auth`.

When I start the App, Firebase tells me that the app doesn't communicate with the firebase Server. Any suggestions where the Problem could be?

That's the changes in Code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context);


            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
```

`FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context);` was added by me.

Comment: What do you want to use Firebase? For push notification?